# Php script file upload is not working with no errors

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a script that uploaded files and worked fine until 3 days ago where it start showing errors.

I am working on Centos 7.8 machine with php 7.4 and nginx 1.19.
The file I am trying to upload is a 12MB xlx file with 76502 rows and 32 columns.

I checked the max_file_upload_size and I increased it to 20M.

My nginx configuration is

```
server {
    if ($host = komy.eody.gov.gr) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        server_name komy.eody.gov.gr vpn.komy.eody.gov.gr;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;


}
upstream fastcgi_backend {
        server unix:/run/php7.4-fpm-komyeody.sock;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name komy.eody.gov.gr vpn.komy.eody.gov.gr;
        root /home/eodyuser/komy.eody.gov.gr/www;
        index index.php;
        client_max_body_size 20M;
        rewrite ^/incidents/group-incidents.html$ http://komy.eody.gov.gr/group-incidents.html redirect;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/komy.eody.gov.gr/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/komy.eody.gov.gr/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout 24h;
        keepalive_timeout 300s;

        # OCSP stapling
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;

        # HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (63072000 seconds)
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000" always;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/komy.eody.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/komy.eody_error.log;

#       location ~* \.(?:css|js|map|jpe?g|gif|png)$ { }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$args;
        }

        location ~\.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass fastcgi_backend;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
        }
}
```

The $data ['file'] is populated on the controller with the following

```
 if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {
            $data['file'] = $_FILES['files'];
            $data['id'] = 0;
        }
```

print_r from ($_FILES['files'] ) is

```
Array ( [files] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => 03012022.xlsx ) [type] => Array ( [0] => ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) ) )
```

Access log entry:

```
79.129.63.234 - - [07/Jan/2022:11:48:59 +0200] "POST /idika-xls-import.html HTTP/2.0" 200 82 "https://komy.eody.gov.gr/idika-xls-import.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0"
```

After I increased the log level of nginx to notice I got the following warning:

```
2022/01/07 12:22:41 [warn] 7045#7045: *117 a client request body is buffered to a temporary file /var/cache/nginx/client_temp/0000000013, client: 79.129.63.234, server: komy.eody.gov.gr, request: "POST /idika-xls-import.html HTTP/2.0", host: "komy.eody.gov.gr", referrer: "https://komy.eody.gov.gr/idika-xls-import.html"
```

The script is I am usging for the upload:

```
if (isset($data['file'])) {
            foreach ($data['file']['name'] as $k => $f) {
                if ( !is_uploaded_file($data['file']['tmp_name'][$k])) {
                    echo json_encode($data['file']);
                    continue;
                }
                $newFileName = time() . '.xlsx';
                $path_to_file = JPATH_SITE . "/images/import/" . $newFileName;
                if (move_uploaded_file($data['file']['tmp_name'][$k], $path_to_file)) {
                    $this->saveFiletoDB($newFileName);
                }
            }
        }
```

The

```
echo json_encode($data['file']);
```

is for debugging reasons and its output is

```
{"name":["03012022_1202.xlsx"],"type":[""],"tmp_name":[""],"error":[1],"size":[0]}
```

As you can see it has error:1 and size: 0.

Is there a way to get info abotu this error?

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Please check your error logs.

Comment: @NicoHaase please check my update on the issue

Comment: What do you mean by that? You haven't updated your question so far

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the issue.

Comment: @Chalas please check my update on the issue

Comment: @NicoHaase Reall sorry I had a network issue and I thought I had posted the update. Please check now.

Comment: @ADyson Sorry the files I work wth and the correspodnig application contains sensitive information and I can not send you either any of the files nor I can give you some testing access. The information on my post are enough to understand the situation.

Comment: "it start showing errors" - can you explain that further? If everything worked before, what did you change?

Comment: Try deleting the folder's content that you store the files and try uploading something again. It might had reached its allocated limit and cannot fit anything else in there.

Comment: `I can not send you either any of the files nor I can give you some testing access`...I didn't ask for any of that. I asked for a [mre] to be provided in your question. That's how Stackoverflow works. We don't go in and debug your systems for you.

Comment: `There is not entry in error log files`...what are your error logging settings in php.ini? move_uploaded files can issue warnings, make sure you're logging those, as well as full-on errors.

Comment: @Chalas I tried it, its the same result.

Comment: Are you sure that the file you're trying to upload is not corrupted?

Comment: `echo json_encode($data['file']); is for debugging reasons and its output is`...so according to your code, if you're seeing that output, it means that `is_uploaded_file` returned false, and your data was not processed any further (due to the `continue`). And since `"tmp_name":[""]` in the JSON is empty, it's easy to see why. Where exactly did you populate `$data` from? Is it a direct copy of `$_FILES`? How are you sending the upload request? What you've shown still doesn't enable us to fully trace the issue to its source.

Comment: @ADyson Sory, I have updated my post with more info. I am not sure If it is ok for a reproducable example.

Comment: `I am not sure If it is ok for a reproducable example`...wel if you take that code, and nothing else, in a HTML file / PHP script, and run it on your system, does the same problem occur? Is what you've provided enough code to actually run it from beginning to end? Is there still any code which can be removed, without it preventing the code from running, or preventing the problem from occurring? Ask yourself those questions, and actually try it out, and then you'll know :-)

Comment: Anyway, if the tmp_name is null in the original $_FILES array, then it suggests that either the client-side code (which you still haven't shown - hint! :-)) doesn't send the file properly for some reason, or the max file size hasn't been increased properly, maybe the setting is not applied yet or something. Did you definitely amend the correct php.ini file? Did you restart the webserver afterwards? Also I don't know nginx, maybe it has its own file size limit settings? Might be worth some research.

Comment: upload_max_filesize is not the only limit, did you check post_max_size too in php.ini? You showed some access log entry, but is tehre no error log entry?